# Show/hide a div on onmouseout/onmouseover, but only on top/left/right?

Tags: html, css, hover

Is there a way to recognize, where the mouse moved on an element? I have a div, which I show or hide on onmouseover and onmouseout of a menu item (li).So when the user moves the mouse over the menu item, the div is shown. When the user moves the mouse left, right or top of the menu item, the div is hidden. Only when the user moves the mouse down, the div should not be hidden because the user should be able to click the content of the div.

Is there a standard way of solving those problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your code along with a jsFiddle link for the code in issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the elements inside any element you want, am using `ul li` and `div` which am setting to `display: none;` and on `li:hover` am setting it to `display: block;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kyTrF/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li>A <div>Show A Content</div></li>
        <li>B <div>Show B Content</div></li>
        <li>C <div>Show C Content</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.wrap ul li div {
    display: none;
}

.wrap ul li:hover div {
    display: block;
}
```